# Как в sql можно получить таблицу по её имени?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Необходимо передать в хранимую процедуру в качестве параметра имя таблицы и дальше с ней работать. Подскажите как  в sql можно получить таблицу по её имени? Существует ли какая ни будь библиотечная функция?

Comment: какой именно sql? (ms sql? my sql?) и как именно хотите с этой таблицей работать? просто выбрать какие-то заранее известные колонки?

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: @Vlad Это называется mssql

Comment: Что значит получить таблицу по ее имени?

Comment: что бы работать можно было как обычно,  т.е. если бы в sql на писать [ИМЯ_БАЗЫ].[ИМЯ_ТАБЛ].[имя_поля]     `SELECT myTable.myColomn from myTable` - при этом поля видно

Answer (score 2):

Если все, кроме имени таблицы, заранее известно - то можно использовать [`sp_executeSql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx):

```sql
DECLARE @tableName sysname = 'TT_Tasks' -- пришло параметром

-- готовый запрос, в который нужно подставить имя таблицы
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM [' + @tableName + ']' 

EXEC sp_executeSql @sql
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант по моему не пойдёт пробовал подобный код. Дело в том что запрос большой, переменных много и этот вариант не подошёл!!! С кавычками там беда просто так как запрос на пол листа. Может другой вариант есть???

Comment: @Vlad насколько я знаю - нет. если запрос большой и много переменных - то хранимки - не лучший выбор. стоит посмотреть в сторону генерации SQL там, откуда вы хранимку вызываете (вместо вызова самой хранимки)

Comment: В сайбесе вроде динамические запросы в процедурах можно было конструировать. И пишут, в MS функции есть https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx  Если это так, может просто передать имя таблицы как текст и сконструировать запрос ...

Comment: @Mike эта ссылка на sp_executeSql. в моем ответе - пример с sp_executeSql :) могу добавить ссылку, но топикастеру он все равно не нравится

Comment: @PashaPash Блин, опять как то вскользь прочитал сообщение и коменты :(